# What is the meaning of a single-use local variable being final?

Tags: java

While working in an existing codebase I came across something similar to this.

```
public static int getDatePlusDaysInMillis(int days) {
    final int DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    return System.currentTimeMillis() + DAY * days;
}
```

The logic itself is not important, as I modified the code a bit so I wasn't copying & pasting business code.

What I wanted to bring attention to was `final int DAY`. Is there any reason to declare `DAY` as `final`? It's scoped to this method and only used once within it. It's not hurting anything, but I thought it looked odd and wanted to ask if there is any meaning to this variable being declared `final`.

Comment: It shows intent. I think that's the only gain here. If it shouldn't be changed, it shouldn't be allowed to be changed.

Comment: It's slightly better than hard coding magic numbers without a label. Of course, it assumes that every day is exactly 24 hours (which is not quite correct).

Comment: In general every variable should be `final` unless there are reasons not to.

Comment: I don't call those "variables;" I call them "constants."

Comment: @PM77-1 if every variable will be final, than they will no longer be variables, but consstants - so it is invalid .

Comment: @PM77-1 Functional programming pounds that into you. I think it's a good lesson in general.

Comment: Not all final variables are constants. Consider `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { final int j = i; /* ... */ }`

Comment: @kaya3: What would be the point of that?

Comment: @kaya3 semanticaly you are wrong. It is still final **in its scope** -  but I know what you meant (but still it is only "kind of valid")

Comment: @Antoniossss - Please take a little bit of time to read before responding to comments.

Comment: Wasn't it edited??:> Obviously i took a bit - without that there would be no reference.

Comment: @Antoniossss In Java, *"A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression (§15.28)."* ([JLS §4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)) In that example, `i` is not a constant expression. So no, what I said is correct.

Comment: And that is wrong - the fact it is in JLS does not make it right - variables can vary, constants cannot.

Comment: The fact that it's in the JLS makes it right **by definition**.

Comment: I don't know which definition but that definition is wrong then. "Variable" is not a Java only contept thus its definition in JLS does not make it "the only source of truth" I think it is just a matter of naming though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a point to doing this. When declared `final`, the variable `DAY` is a constant variable as defined by the Java Language Specification ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)):

> A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression (§15.28).

This means some optimisations are done at compile-time, which aren't done when the variable is not declared `final`. We can see the different bytecode depending on whether you use `final` or not:

```java
public class Test {
    public long withoutFinal(int days) {
        int DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        return System.currentTimeMillis() + DAY * days;
    }
    public long withFinal(int days) {
        final int DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        return System.currentTimeMillis() + DAY * days;
    }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
  public long withoutFinal(int);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2          // int 86400000
       2: istore_2
       3: invokestatic  #3          // Method java/lang/System.currentTimeMillis:()J
       6: iload_2
       7: iload_1
       8: imul
       9: i2l
      10: ladd
      11: lreturn

  public long withFinal(int);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #3          // Method java/lang/System.currentTimeMillis:()J
       3: ldc           #2          // int 86400000
       5: iload_1
       6: imul
       7: i2l
       8: ladd
       9: lreturn
```

The version with `final` is shorter, because it uses one `ldc` (load constant) operation where the other version uses a `ldc`, an `istore_2` to store the constant to a local variable, and an `iload_2` to load it from that local variable.

This difference would likely be optimised away at runtime by the JIT if the method is called many times, but using `final` means the `.class` file is slightly smaller, and there is a small performance benefit if the method is not called many times.

Comment: I think its not small, its neglectable.

Comment: Maybe you could add, that it also documents intent to other developers, that the value should not be changed, resp. they can be assured they don't have to seek for possible modifcations, and also that it can be used for parameters as well?

Comment: The intent becomes especially necessary, if you want to use the variable inside a lambda function, as it is required that it is 'final or effectively final' (by coincidence not modified)

Comment: @Antoniossss The code it's in may be quite old - who knows? Java used to be a lot slower, because the bytecode was interpreted at runtime without a JIT. But obviously if something is negligible then it is small, so I don't know what your objection is.

Comment: *But obviously if something is negligible then it is small* this fits saying that "its just is" as well so its pointless.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say there, but there is an objective difference between the two ways of writing the code, which people who have this question would presumably like to know about. Whether or not the difference is too small to be worth writing the code this way is a matter of opinion, and my answer expressed no opinions either way.

Comment: @kaya3I agree with your last comment. Even if the performance boost is negligible, this does explain why one would choose to write code like this.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason is to forbid consecutive assignement to that varible (for whatever reasons in given context), nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

DAY should be a static final member declared in the class and not in the method so that it can be reused and not constantly recreated. This is a standard convention.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

```java
private static final int DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

This can also be defined in a simpler way.

```java
private static final long DAY = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);
```

Comment: Why should it be?

Comment: "Could be" would be more appopriate, but should be is just a missuse

Comment: Nevermind, it definitely should. It should be used because you're not recreating the integer each time. This is standard convention.

Comment: Which convention?

Comment: Look for the constant section https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: There is no such convention, sorry. Link says that semantics allows "that or that" but there is no convention regarding it (because there is no meaningfull impact to any of cases)

Comment: I don't think this is quite correct @Jason. The link you yourself provided says: *Note: If a primitive type ... is defined as a constant and the value is known at compile time, the compiler replaces the constant name everywhere in the code with its value.* So we can't be sure this variable is going to be recreated in runtime, can we?

Comment: @jrook your answer implicitly acknowledges Json's answer that value should be created/computed only once and not everytime. The only difference is that - you assumed that compiler will do it (by correcting bad coding practice) while Json argues that programmer should be aware and write it in that way at the first place.

Comment: @Jags please see [kaya3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60572266/2928853).

Comment: `TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)` is a little bit worse since it's not a constant expression, so the compiler won't do certain optimisations that it will do if you write `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` instead.

Comment: By the way, the integer isn't recreated every time even if it's local; the version with a `final` local variable actually compiles to *exactly the same bytecode* as the version with a `static final` variable, as long as you don't use `TimeUnit`.

Comment: Long story short, don't actually do this if you are not going to use `DAY` globally in your class. It will not improve performance and while it might not hurt performance either, it still creates confusion for others reading the code. OP's way is the right way to go about this.

Comment: @jrook best practice is to declare final variable at class level and not inside method. We all agree to this conceptually.